# Check textbox input auto increase number determine by input total records

Tags: c#, winforms

Two textbox for checking input result to determine how many records need to generate.

First **textbox**  use for auto increment number:user might input **"000000"**  or **"001000"**  this part will be tricky if user input "**090000**" or "**123456**" refer to code  variable getSequance.

Second **textbox** use for check total records need to generate refer to code variable  getrecords .

what i have try auto increase last digit number:

```
private void input_autoincrement()
{
     string getrecords = "10";     // first textbox:records generate
     string getSequance = "000000"; //second textbox:auto increment number

     for( int ix = 0; ix < Convert.ToInt32(getrecords); ix++)
     {
         string autoincrno = ix.ToString().PadLeft(1,'0');  // if autoincrno default value is "123456" how to make it change here?
     }
}
```

I have a problem on if autoincrno have default value such as "123456"  the way i do it will reset the value to "000000".

Comment: I have read this post carefully and do not see any question within its text. What is the problem?

Comment: @JohnWu  with the loop i can check the records user input but how to auto increment the getsequance (second textbox)

Comment: I do not know what "auto" means in this context. Since this is all done via code, everything is sort of automatic, isn't it? I think you mean that you wish for a variable to increment in response to a particular event, e.g. if the user adds a record. Are you having trouble detecting that event? Or are you having trouble doing the math to add 1? Or what?

Comment: @JohnWu i have trouble to doing the math on add 1. i have update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to convert ix to a 6 digit string with leading 0's

```
for( int ix = 0; ix < Convert.ToInt32(getrecords); ix++)
{
    string autoincrno = ix.ToString("D6"); // 000001, 000002 etc
}
```

Based on your comment, if you have a string that represents a number and you want to increment it, you can parse it to an integer.

```
string autoincro = "123456";

int temp = int.Parse(autoincrno);

temp++;

autoincrno = temp.ToString("D6"); // 123457
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response i want to know if autoincrno already have default value as "123456" is there any way to increase it ?

Comment: yes this is what i want, but still have a little problem if the autoincrno default value is "123479" with your code will start generate at "123480" and "123479" is skip

Comment: The last three lines are just an example of how you can increment a string. You can put them anywhere in your code that you would need to use them. If want to display the default value the first time then don't increment it before you display it.

Comment: If you look at it another way, if your starting value is 000000, that is the number of records previously generated, and then first time you increment it then it becomes 000001. If your starting value is 123479 then that was, again, the number of records that had PREVIOUSLY been generated. The first time you increment it then it should become 123480.

Comment: i use not good way to do it, if(ix!=0)  the 123479 will not do anything for the first time, and while the loop continue it will increment to 123480, using this way after loop for 10 time the final result will be 123488